# have registrate/log in program but can't save more then one profile

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I hacked my own prgeam using Java but i can't make the program to save more then one prfile it gives me an error message for Unknown Source.

code for Serialized Registrated profiles

```
int br1 = 4, br = 0;
            ArrayList<Object> dObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
            try {

                FileInputStream FileIn = new FileInputStream("users.ser");
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(FileIn);
                dObjects = (ArrayList<Object>) in.readObject();
                in.close();
                FileIn.close();

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception

                e2.printStackTrace();
                return;

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                c.printStackTrace();
            }
            br = (int) dObjects.get(0);
            String name = new String(textField.getText());
            char[] pass = passwordField.getPassword();
            String password = new String(pass);
            ArrayList<User> rUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
            User[] rUsers2 = new User[br1];
            rUsers.add(new User(name, password));
            System.out.println(br);
            System.out.println(rUsers.size());
            rUsers2[br] = rUsers.get(0);
            br++;
            br1++;
            ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();
            data.add(br);
            data.add(br1);
            data.add(rUsers2);
            try {

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("users.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                out.writeObject(data);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                System.out.println("Yes");

            } catch (IOException e2) {

                e2.printStackTrace();

            }
            Login nw = new Login();
            nw.Login1();
            frmRegistrate.dispose();

        }
    });
```

code for deserialized Registrated profiles

```
String name = new String(textField.getText());
            String password = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
            int b = 0;
            ArrayList<Object> dObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
            try {

                FileInputStream FileIn = new FileInputStream("users.ser");
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(FileIn);
                dObjects = (ArrayList<Object>) in.readObject();
                in.close();
                FileIn.close();

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception

                e2.printStackTrace();
                return;

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                c.printStackTrace();
            }
            int rebr = (int) dObjects.get(0);
            User[] lUsers = new User[rebr];
            lUsers = (User[]) dObjects.get(2);
            System.out.println(rebr);
            System.out.println(lUsers);
            while (b < rebr) {

                System.out.println(lUsers[b].getName());

                if (lUsers[b].getName().equals(name) && lUsers[b].getPassword().equals(password)) {

                    b = rebr;
                    frmLogin.dispose();
                    Menu nw = new Menu();
                    nw.Menu1();

                } else {
                    b++;
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

I hope that someone can help me with this problem.
I am sorry if my question is strange but i am new in this forum and in the programing at all

Comment: You need to include the error message and/or stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't the cause of the error (we don't know where your error is because you didn't give a stack trace) then it will be

```
    ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();
    data.add(br);
    data.add(br1);
    data.add(rUsers2);
```

Java doesn't know how to store an `int` type which `br` and `br1` are as an `object` which is the type of the array list.

It seems like you need to go read up on java a bit more, and do some more googling on the error before posting a specific question here, because the odds are that you are having the same error many other people have had.